# JavaScript auto arranging digram engine

Tags: javascript, canvas

A friend of mine, who is a chemistry tutor, came up of the idea of a web-app that would interactively display the chemical structure as it is being manipulated. It does not need to be accurate, it is only meant to interactively show elementary chemistry, in which all elements try to join to one another to complete their outer most bond.

So the question is, is there a JavaScript (canvas?) diagram engine, that optimally rearrange nodes on display. As it is being manipulated (IE. Removing hydrogen from oxygen in water, with oxygen as the central node)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In canvas? Yeah.

[Canvasmol](http://alteredqualia.com/canvasmol/), which was released one year ago.

And the [whole chemdoodle suite](http://web.chemdoodle.com/demos/molgrabber-3d). Molgrabber is just one part, be sure to check out the other parts.